# I cannot get ADB to see my Nexus One device

Tags: android

Mac OSX 10.6.4
Nexus One Android 2.2
The command adb devices will list my emulators and also my Droid Eris (Android 2.2) but nothing shows for the Nexus One

I have searched extensively and failed to find any answer or suggestions, any help most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power cycle and reboot everything including the phone.

Comment: I have the same problem but reboot doesn't help. Any other advice?

Comment: Try enabling usb debugging, see if that helps.